# Not able to add publisher name in Programs and Features window (Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Programs and Features)

Tags: cmd, window, installanywhere

Publisher name not showing the **"Programs and Features"** window.

The **installler.exe** file are created using the **Installanywhere Tool**

I executed the below mentioned command.

```
cd\
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1\Bin
signtool.exe sign /f "D:\Softwares\AAINC.pfx" /p "password" "D:\VM\Installer.exe"
```

When i double click on the installer it showing the publisher name and also verify right click on the installer it showing the digital signature pannel that containing the publisher name.

```
But when i installed the installer it does not showing the publisher name.
**location :** Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Programs and Features
```

Why it is not showing the publisher name. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Paths and file names with spaces have to be quoted: `"C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1\Bin\signtool.exe" sign /f "D:\Softwares\AAINC.pfx" /p "password" "D:\VM\Installer.exe"` should work (given the path to the tool and the parameter syntax is correct; can't verify)

Comment: The problem like in the control panel the publisher name not updating, it;s still showing the application name.